# python3 - list method - variable/list equality and list modified following this equality

Tags: python-3.x, list, variables, methods

Why is the list modified while I only attribute a value to a variable? I would like to understand what happens deep down in the sublayers of the interpreter.
Example:

```
fruits = ['apple', 'blueberry', 'banana', 'cherry', 'apple', 'lemon']
item = fruits.pop()
print(item)
print(fruits)

# Output
lemon
['apple', 'blueberry', 'banana', 'cherry', 'apple']
```

Logically, the list 'fruits' should not be modified since i am just typing an equality.

Comment: Please review the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) or [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_pop.asp) tutorial about how `pop` works -- it *changes* the list **and** returns the value *removed*.

Comment: I understand this but I wrote an equality so I am just specifying that I want a variable to be assigned with a value and I never wrote that I want my value (list) to be modified.

Comment: But that's what `pop` does. It *changes* the list, regardless of whether you assign its return value or not.

Comment: Your answer is clear. I have two processes, one that modifies a list and another which is the returned value.